# Forming non-standard hyperlinks in CRM 2011 dialogs

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

In CRM 2011 it's really easy to link to another CRM record or to link to an external website from within dialogs and emails. However, when I try to create non-http links (such as sip: or tel:) they do not work. I have tried using the hyperlink button and also using the hyperlink syntax:

`<hyperlink>`

`<name>555-555-5555</name>`

`<value>sip:5555555555</value>`

`</hyperlink>`

As a result, it looks like a proper hyperlink, but clicking it does nothing. When examining the source, it appears as if the hyperlink is linking to the dialog page itself.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: The url to what does it point?

Comment: That is not a proper link; it should read sip://5555555555

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a HTML web resource in CRM and access it by URL + a querystring parameter. You could then disseminate the querystring and "redirect" to the desired resource using something similar to:

```
var myFixedUrl = ParseQuerystringIntoUrl();
window.open(myFixedUrl);
```

Where `ParseQuerystringIntoUrl` is your own custom function to strip details from the querystring and reconstruct your desired URL.